# AVPlayer seekToTime goes to a different location for mp4 and HLS

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have an MP4 file that I have encoded using Apple's mediafilesegmenter into the HLS format using the following command:

```
mediafilesegmenter -I -s video.mp4
```

In my iOS 8 app, I can load both the MP4 and the HLS files in an AVPlayer and they playback correctly. However, when I try to jump to a specific location, the MP4 goes to the correct frame but the HLS is always slightly off (just by a few frames, but still noticeable - HIGH accuracy is required in my app). I am seeking to the location using the following code:

```
float preferredTimeScale = 100000;
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:playbackURL];
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startEvent.floatValue, preferredTimeScale);     
[playerItem seekToTime:startTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

I have tried different values for the the preferredTimeScale, including NSEC_PER_SEC and playerItem.asset.duration.timescale, but none of these seem to help the accuracy. I have also tried changing the target duration when running the mediafilesegmenter from the default 10 seconds to 1 second, but that hasn't helped the accuracy either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the seekToTime accuracy for HLS videos so it is the same as an MP4 video?

EDIT: Here is what my m3u8 file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1066148@0
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1007304@1066148
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1077616@2073452
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1012756@3151068
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1064832@4163824
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1007492@5228656
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1054304@6236148
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:983240@7290452
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:948648@8273692
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1003356@9222340
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:823252@10225696
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:828140@11048948
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:990384@11877088
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1026856@12867472
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:969328@13894328
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:946956@14863656
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:904092@15810612
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:723612@16714704
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:890180@17438316
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1021404@18328496
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1076676@19349900
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1011440@20426576
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1065772@21438016
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:926840@22503788
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:852768@23430628
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1038512@24283396
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:760272@25321908
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:959552@26082180
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:936240@27041732
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1094536@27977972
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1042272@29072508
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1031556@30114780
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1044340@31146336
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:986248@32190676
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1002980@33176924
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1043400@34179904
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:962936@35223304
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:770612@36186240
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:502336@36956852
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:344040@37459188
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:297228@37803228
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:375248@38100456
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:342348@38475704
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:342348@38818052
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:335580@39160400
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:316404@39495980
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:300988@39812384
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:324864@40113372
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:419992@40438236
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:353440@40858228
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:319412@41211668
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:296664@41531080
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:301552@41827744
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:363968@42129296
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:692780@42493264
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1096040@43186044
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:947896@44282084
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1105064@45229980
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:999596@46335044
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:936992@47334640
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:957296@48271632
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1053740@49228928
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1034000@50282668
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1042460@51316668
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:998656@52359128
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1068028@53357784
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:902776@54425812
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:914808@55328588
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1041144@56243396
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1021968@57284540
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:913116@58306508
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:353252@59219624
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:319224@59572876
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:361148@59892100
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:377128@60253248
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:381264@60630376
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:339528@61011640
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:379948@61351168
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:426008@61731116
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:347988@62157124
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:347988@62505112
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:409088@62853100
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:410592@63262188
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:439920@63672780
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:499704@64112700
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:307380@64612404
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:276924@64919784
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:311516@65196708
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:442176@65508224
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:753128@65950400
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:986812@66703528
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1051108@67690340
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1048100@68741448
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:984744@69789548
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1099800@70774292
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:999972@71874092
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1048100@72874064
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1043964@73922164
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1004296@74966128
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:906348@75970424
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1068404@76876772
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1048100@77945176
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1035504@78993276
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:995460@80028780
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1085136@81024240
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1019900@82109376
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1044904@83129276
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1052048@84174180
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1008056@85226228
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1027420@86234284
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1031368@87261704
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1090024@88293072
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1028172@89383096
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030616@90411268
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030052@91441884
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1041520@92471936
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1032496@93513456
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1047160@94545952
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029112@95593112
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1053176@96622224
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1042460@97675400
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1032308@98717860
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1028172@99750168
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1027044@100778340
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1000160@101805384
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:937744@102805544
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:970268@103743288
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:961808@104713556
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:984368@105675364
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:842428@106659732
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:963124@107502160
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:888112@108465284
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1056184@109353396
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1060884@110409580
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:975720@111470464
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1111268@112446184
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1020652@113557452
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1015952@114578104
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:997528@115594056
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1103372@116591584
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030804@117694956
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:710640@118725760
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1117096@119436400
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:948460@120553496
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:975344@121501956
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1025352@122477300
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1035692@123502652
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1008432@124538344
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:988128@125546776
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1038324@126534904
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1018208@127573228
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1061072@128591436
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1017456@129652508
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029864@130669964
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1064268@131699828
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1028924@132764096
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1046596@133793020
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1040016@134839616
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1024224@135879632
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1048476@136903856
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1042460@137952332
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030428@138994792
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1046784@140025220
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1033624@141072004
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1032684@142105628
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1026480@143138312
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1059192@144164792
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1039828@145223984
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1038136@146263812
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1042836@147301948
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:951468@148344784
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:815920@149296252
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:751812@150112172
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:887924@150863984
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1087016@151751908
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:845060@152838924
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:830772@153683984
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1049416@154514756
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:871192@155564172
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:955040@156435364
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1099612@157390404
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:903340@158490016
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:993392@159393356
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:766664@160386748
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:929848@161153412
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:971020@162083260
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:988692@163054280
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:979480@164042972
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1088708@165022452
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1063516@166111160
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:774372@167174676
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1022908@167949048
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:946392@168971956
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:950904@169918348
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1013508@170869252
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:902212@171882760
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:980232@172784972
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:875140@173765204
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1089084@174640344
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029864@175729428
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1063516@176759292
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1039452@177822808
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1033812@178862260
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1037948@179896072
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1026292@180934020
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1028548@181960312
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1031556@182988860
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1058628@184020416
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1052048@185079044
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1034188@186131092
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1036632@187165280
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1021028@188201912
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1043400@189222940
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1044528@190266340
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029112@191310868
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1057500@192339980
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1028548@193397480
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1037760@194426028
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029112@195463788
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1054868@196492900
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1044152@197547768
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030428@198591920
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1047160@199622348
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1040392@200669508
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1046032@201709900
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1040392@202755932
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:830020@203796324
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:739968@204626344
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1001100@205366312
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1016328@206367412
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1039452@207383740
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1056184@208423192
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1050544@209479376
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1029300@210529920
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1037760@211559220
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1034000@212596980
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1049228@213630980
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1030992@214680208
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1050732@215711200
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:992452@216761932
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1051672@217754384
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1072164@218806056
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:947520@219878220
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96829,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:775500@220825740
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1119164@221601240
main.ts
#EXTINF:9.96830,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1032684@222720404
main.ts
#EXTINF:3.96229,    
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:357200@223753088
main.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Can you show the m3u8 file?

Comment: you can use shorter segment length - probably dont have keyframe for the required seek time

Comment: I had the same thought and tried setting the segment length to 1 second, which is the minimum value the mediafilesegmenter allows, but I didn't notice any change. It's strange that the .mp4 file has enough information to do the seek accuratly, but the live streaming files don't.

Comment: maybe the EXTINF value is not accurate? did you try to look at the ts using mediainfo?

Comment: I have not looked at the ts using mediainfo. Can you use that to tell if the  EXTINF value is accurate?